# Call subscription's informations from Checkout client in Stripe

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, stripe-payments

I use Checkout client for my Saas and I have difficulties storing the subscriptions informations in a MongoDB database (my backend is in NodeJS) for each use. Can I do that with Checkout client integration ?

Answer (score 0):

Stripe Checkout won't do anything related to database storing, but you can listen for the `checkout.session.completed` webhook event and then store that data in Mongo: https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed

Comment: Thanks ! I don't really understand how to do that, and how to link the billing infos for example in mu user database.